# Inserting an item into a list in descending order in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to write a program for a BDI agent who moves in a grid targeting goals. The goals are defined with their grid location and weight as goal(X,Y,S). Each perceived goal is to be inserted to a list of intentions in descending order of their weight. If the goal is already in the list it should be ignored.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
incorporate_goals([], _, Intentions, Intentions).
incorporate_goals([Goal|Tail], Beliefs, Intentions, Intentions1) :-
   member(Goal, Intentions),
   !,
   incorporate_goals(Tail, Beliefs, Intentions, Intentions1).
incorporate_goals([Goal|Tail], Beliefs, Intentions, Intentions1) :-
   not(member(Goal, Intentions)),
   insert_goal(Goal, Intentions, Beliefs, Intentions_updated),
   incorporate_goals(Tail, Beliefs, Intentions_updated, Intentions1).

insert_goal(Goal, Intentions, _, [[Goal, []]|Intentions]).
insert_goal(Goal, [H|Intentions], Beliefs, [Goal,H|Intentions1]) :-
   eval(Goal, H, Beliefs).
insert_goal(Goal, [H|Intentions], Beliefs, [Goal,H|Intentions1]) :-
   not(eval(Goal,H,Beliefs)),
   insert_goal(Goal, [Intentions], Beliefs, [Intentions1]).

eval(goal(_,_,S1), goal(_,_,S2), _) :-
   S1 > S2,
   !.   
eval(goal(X1,Y1,S1), goal(X2,Y2,S2), [at(X,Y)]) :-
   S1 == S2,
   distance((X,Y), (X1,Y1), D1),
   distance((X,Y), (X2,Y2), D2),
   D1 < D2.
```

My questions are:

1. identical goals are not detected by the member/2 properly
2. the goals just get inserted to the head of the list instead of being ordered in descending order.

I've been stuck at this point for quite a while now. I would very much appreciate it if you can point out the mistake.

Comment: I see a few issues right off, not necessarily related to your "questions" (which are actually statements). `Intentions1` appears to be a singleton in your second `insert_goal/4` clause. That should be addressed. If it's intentional (no pun intended...recursively) then use `_Intentions1` to rid yourself of the warning. There's also an asymmetry in your handling of the 4th argument. The first clause has `[[Goal, []] | Intentions]` which treats the head as a sublist, whereas the other clauses have `[Goal, H | Intentions]` which doesn't treats the head as two discrete elements.

Comment: It's unclear what the structure of your `Intentions` list should be based upon the code you wrote.

Comment: Intentions list is supposed to be a a list that contains sublists of goal and a path to get to the goal. 

`Intentions[[Goal,Path]|Tail]`

In terms of the insert/4, I believe the issue is with the way I have done recursion.

Comment: I think there's more wrong with it than the recursion per my comment. You aren't treating the structure of the list consistently. If you take, for example, the clause `insert_goal(Goal, Intentions, _, [[Goal, []]|Intentions])`, This `Goal` would not be found by the call, `member(Goal, Intentions)`.